# display data using like operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to put a condition where my description column contains below data in sql server using like operator .

`Transfer Group from 'GEUC Service Desk' to 'GEUC Tier 2 Security'`

Please let me know the condition for this

Sample data

```
Ticket No   Description
1234        Transfer Group from 'GEUC Service Desk' to 'GEUC Tier 2 Security'
5464        Transfer Group from 'GEUC Service Desk' to 'GEUC Tier 2 Security'
5534        No Transfer
7677        No Transfer
```

Here I need to show the tickets where  description column contains `Transfer Group from 'GEUC Service Desk' to 'GEUC Tier 2 Security'`

Comment: I am using below condition but not getting data                                              
where Description like 'Transfer Group from ''GEUC Proximity Support'' to ''EUC Tier 2 Security'''

Comment: Post sample data and the expected result.

Comment: My description column contains Transfer Group from 'GEUC Service Desk' to 'GEUC Tier 2 Security'.   I need to display the rows for above data

Comment: You are the only one who understands this.

Comment: Ticket No Description
1234 Transfer Group from 'GEUC Service Desk' to 'GEUC Tier 2 Security'
5464 Transfer Group from 'GEUC Service Desk' to 'GEUC Tier 2 Security'
5534 No Transfer
7677 No Transfer
Here I need to show the tickets where  description column contains Transfer Group from 'GEUC Service Desk' to 'GEUC Tier 2 Security'

Comment: Try adding `%....%` wildcards. But if you want to compare the full description you don't need `LIKE` but a simple `=`. And maybe the spaces only look like spaces, try copying the text instead of keying it in

Answer (score 0):

I think you would use `update`:

```
update t
    set transfer_group = 'GEUC Tier 2 Security'
    where transfer_group = 'GEUC Service Desk';
```

Answer (score 0):

With `LIKE`:

```
select * from tablename where description 
like '%Transfer Group from ''GEUC Service Desk'' to ''GEUC Tier 2 Security''%'
```

but if this is the whole value of the column, you can use `=`:

```
select * from tablename where description =
'Transfer Group from ''GEUC Service Desk'' to ''GEUC Tier 2 Security'''
```

Answer (score 0):

For escaping from ' in Mysql you can use \ or '. You can solve your problem with:

`SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE Description LIKE '%Transfer Group from \'GEUC    Service Desk\' to \'GEUC Tier 2 Security\'';`

OR:

`SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE Description LIKE '%Transfer Group from ''GEUC    Service Desk'' to ''GEUC Tier 2 Security''';`